# Order object keys according to key list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list for order of field to display

```
field_order = ["name", "age", "birthday"]
```

I got a list of objects like this

```
_data_set = {
    "age": 23,
    "birthday": "2000-12-12"
    "name": "A"
}
```

I need to order Object keys according to `field_order`.

Expected result:

```
_data_set = {
    "name": "A",
    "age": 23,
    "birthday": "2000-12-12"
}
```

Comment: @Saurabh Agrawal please closely look at my question. Your mentioned question does not fulfiled my requirements anymore.

Comment: Do you want to sort by keys or values? If you want to sort by values, may I ask you what it is the purpose?

Comment: not duplicate because here question is to sort with both string and number

Comment: for table header I use `field_order` and for table data I use `_data_set` but for `_data_set` keys order table header and data column mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key order is chronological in JavaScript since ES2015, so we can order like so:

There's a nice article on this: [property-traversal-order-es6](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)

```js
field_order = ["name", "age", "birthday"]
_data_set = {
    "age": 23,
    "birthday": "2000-12-12",
    "name": "A"
};

let result = field_order.reduce( (obj, v) => {
   obj[v] = _data_set[v];
   return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to sort and then just create an object with desired order of keys:

```js
let field_order = ["name", "age", "birthday"];
let _data_set = {
  "age": 23,
  "birthday": "2000-12-12",
  "name": "A"
}

let order = {name: -1, age: 0, birthday: 1};

const result = {};
Object.keys(_data_set)
    .sort((a,b)=> order[a] - order[b])
    .forEach(key=> result[key] = _data_set[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
let new_data_set = {};
for(let item of field_order) {
   new_data_set[item] = _data_set[item];
}
```